# How to suppress page break before \twocolumn?

Tags: page-breaking, two-column

**Problem:** The command `\twocolumn` generates a page break in a LaTeX document that is specified as `\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}`. This specification of the documentclass can not be changed.

**Question:** Is there a way to suppress the page break before the command `\twocolumn`?

**Code Example:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\begin{document}

  Two column text
  % Goal: suppress page break here
  \twocolumn[
    One column text
  ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: No there isn't, use the multicol package if you want twocolumns that start in the middle of a page.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Using the `twocolumn` option to the class sets the document in two columns. Why then do you want to issue a `\twocolumn` in the body of the document? I could understand if you were trying for a `onecolumn` in a `twocolumn` document.  Also `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` are switches, not macros that take arguments.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Thanks for your comment. The switch as used in question allows to insert a one column block before a two column block: `\twocolumn[text in one colum] text in two columns` However, the switch generates a page break.

Comment: @https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182467/thando Yes, that is what the `\onecolumn` and `\twoicolumn` switches do. To get what you want use the `multicolumn` package.

Comment: Unfortunately, the specification of the documentclass can not be changed in this use case. Although, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PeterWilson - \twocolumn[title] will print the title in one column mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you start in [twocolumn] doesn't mean you have to stay there.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\begin{document}
\onecolumn\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```