# Memoir two column table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, two-column

Im struggling with this aspect of the table of contents. I have a one column document but need a two column table of contents. By default, the `\twocoltocetc` produces results undesirable for a one column document, placing the Contents section heading also inside the two column environment instead of placing it normally. I believe this is a limitation of the of the definition on line 7732 of memoir.cls where `\twocolumn` is called. It seems that there is a limitation where the `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` switches always must start on a new page, as indicated by Peter Wilsons remarks found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479818/how-to-suppress-page-break-before-twocolumn#comment1212876_479818).

Peter advices to use the `multicols` environment for such a task, and I have also found an example on page 163 of [memman](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) where the the multicols environment is added to the .toc with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}`

With modifications, I can create the following environment, and when I wrap the entire document in it I can produce the table of contents as desired.

```
\newenvironment{twocoltoc}[1]{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}%
   {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}}
```

This feels rather clunky though. I can also just directly place the `\addtocontents...` instead of use the environment. I would like to have a single call function which acomplishes this goal, similar to `\twocoltocetc`. I need a way to add a line to the end of the `.toc` after the rest of the lines are generated, but I am not quite sure how to achieve this. It has to be in the guts of `starttoc{toc}` but I am unsure of where to find that.

Here is my test file showing what I have so far, it produces a desirable output but is not elegant.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}

\newif\ifwanttwocoltoc
\wanttwocoltocfalse

\NewDocumentCommand{\twocoltoc}{}{
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}%
    \wanttwocoltoctrue
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketoc}{}{
    \tableofcontents
    \ifwanttwocoltoc
        % \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}
}

\begin{document}

\twocoltoc
\maketoc
 
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}


{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}}
\end{document}
```

p.s. there is a typo in the mentioned example, `\end{multocols}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answer goes towards what the OP wants, but there is a slight snag.

```
% twocoltocprob.tex  SE 637513

\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}    %%% OPs code
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}

\newif\ifwanttwocoltoc
\wanttwocoltocfalse

\NewDocumentCommand{\twocoltoc}{}{
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}%
    \wanttwocoltoctrue
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketoc}{}{
    \tableofcontents
    \ifwanttwocoltoc
        % \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}
}

\setlength{\textheight}{0.33\textheight}

\begin{document}

\twocoltoc
\maketoc

\end{comment}  %% end of OPs code

%\begin{comment}  %% my code

\setlength{\textheight}{0.4\textheight}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\twocoltoc}{\tableofcontents%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}}
  
\renewcommand{\twocoltoc}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}
  \tableofcontents}
  

\begin{document}

%%%% regular (my) code for the ToC
\twocoltoc

\end{document}

%%% OPs division codes

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter}

%%%%\end{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}


%% {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}}
\end{document}
```

I think that the output is what the OP wants but when processing the above I get an error message about `file ended scanning use of \next`. However, ignoring this, the output is what I think the OP is after.

Can anyone help with the `\next` problem?

[image]